# String to Int (number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

i have the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'index.php?act=ajax&op=getShippingPrice&id='+shippingID,
      success: function(data) {
        var currentPrice = Number($("#finalPrice").html());
        var newPrice = Number(currentPrice + data);
        $("#finalPrice").html(newPrice);
      }
    });
```

i try to calculate the new price. but i actually get a string of newPrice, which contains the current price, and right after it the data from ajax.

if the current price is 1500, and data from ajax is 10, what i get is 150010, and not 1510.

i also tried to use parseInt, probably didn't use it right.

Comment: Wrap each string in parseInt

Comment: Yes, it's most likely `$('#finalPrice').html()` which outputs a string, instead of an int, using `parseInt` will cast the string to an integer, and instead of the `+` operator `concatenating` a string, it will `add` to the integer.

Comment: Both operands need to be numbers if you want to perform addition.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

Assuming a price with decimals, using `parseFloat`, if not, use `parseInt`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'index.php?act=ajax&op=getShippingPrice&id='+shippingID,
  success: function(data) {
    var currentPrice = parseFloat($("#finalPrice").html());
    var newPrice = currentPrice + parseFloat(data));
    $("#finalPrice").html(newPrice.toFixed(2));
  }
});
```

Comment: And now a toFixed and we are there

Comment: @mplungjan IMHO you yourself are making far too many assumptions about the OP's requirements.  He said he tried `parseInt` so it's reasonable to expect that the fields are actually ints, at which point use of `parseFloat` and `toFixed` are inappropriate.

Comment: Inappropriate is a hard word to use when the thing is a price. It could be added to this solution that "Assuming a price with decimals, use parseFloat, if not, use parseInt" and that would handle any assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like:

```
var newPrice = parseInt(currentPrice) + parseInt(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help You:

```
 var newPrice = 1*currentPrice + 1*data;
```

Multiply by `1` don't change the result but it will change the variable type.

Comment: There are built in functions to do this!

Comment: Yes but there is no reason to take canon to shut sparrow :)

Comment: And You don't even need `Number` function after that.

Comment: You have a totally unnecessary Number in there but that is ok? (And it is cannon and shoot)

Comment: in any event the canonical "short" way to convert a variable to a floating point number (without error checking) is to use `+currentPrice`, not `1 * ...`

Comment: Yes Your right, that's why I have write it's unnecessary right before You. It can be `var newPrice = 1*currentPrice + 1*data;`

Comment: So update your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Convert your HTML-derived value into a number first (and ensure you supply the radix parameter to cope with leading zeroes).

You should also remove any white space that might exist:

```
var currentPrice = parseInt($.trim($("#finalPrice").html()), 10);
var newPrice = currentPrice + data;
```

If the output from the server is not in JSON format then you should also convert the `data` field too before the addition:

```
data = parseInt(data, 10);
```

Finally, if your numbers aren't actually integers, use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: Data will surely be a string

Comment: @mplungjan not if the response is JSON - the OP didn't say.

Comment: I would NEVER trust it to be numeric

Comment: A bare number returned in an HTTP response is legal JSON, so the parsing would depend on the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I could see a space break that...

Comment: @mplungjan yes, a space from the server _could_ break that, but without information from the OP about whether his output is "plain ASCII" or "JSON" you're just picking nits.

Comment: Or introducing OP to defensive coding :)

Comment: The defensive bit is the trim call for the contents of the HTML DOM.  It shouldn't be necessary to "defend" against a server sending valid JSON.  If the JSON isn't valid, it won't even reach this code.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying like this one:

$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'index.php?act=ajax&op=getShippingPrice&id='+shippingID,
      success: function(data) {

```
    var newPrice = Number(currentPrice + Number($("#finalPrice").html()));
    $("#finalPrice").html(newPrice);
  }
});
```

At least you will get error.

Comment: Why wrap numbers in number?